# How to exclude any value in this calculation that is 0

Tags: android, mobile, calculation

I have a calculation in which I have to subtract 5 variable from the total that are all given by the user with an EditText, snd my question is: is there a way to exclude any value (et1, et2, et3, et4, et5) if one of them is 0?
for example if user puts 500 as "totaal" and for et1 & et2 zero and for the rest four I oly want 3*4 being subtracted from the "totaal"

This is the code:

```
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Bereken extends AppCompatActivity {
private Double totaal = null;
TextView Txttotal;
Button k1;
Button k2;
Button k3;
TextView kies;
EditText ET1;
EditText ET2;
EditText ET3;
EditText ET4;
EditText ET5;
double temporary;
double randomdouble;
double formerval;
double totje;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bereken);
    totaal = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("Hannibal");
    Txttotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Tijdelijk);
    Txttotal.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(totaal));
    k1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.optie1);
    k2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.optie2);
    k3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.optie3);
    ET1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    ET2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    ET3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    ET4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    ET5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText11);

    ET1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(!ET1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                double et1 = Double.parseDouble(ET1.getText().toString());
                double et2 = Double.parseDouble(ET2.getText().toString());
                double et3 = Double.parseDouble(ET3.getText().toString());
                double et4 = Double.parseDouble(ET4.getText().toString());
                double et5 = Double.parseDouble(ET5.getText().toString());
                totje = totaal - et1 - et2 - et3 - et4 - et5;
                Txttotal.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(totje));
            }else{
              totaal = totaal + formerval;
              Txttotal.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(totaal));
            }
            randomdouble = temporary;
        }
    });

    ET2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    ET3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    ET4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    ET5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

and this is the error

```
02-16 17:05:11.148 18568-18568/dipp.verlinden E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: dipp.verlinden, PID: 18568
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
at dipp.verlinden.Bereken$1.afterTextChanged(Bereken.java:64)
at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:9195)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:11939)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1047)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:564)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:494)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:34)
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:691)
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:199)
at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:184)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:286)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: question is what for? `x-0=x` so 0 is a [neutral element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) for adding and substracting

Comment: But if a double is 0 the app crashes

Comment: Can you show some code to understand where you're going wrong?

Comment: question the crash then

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 0 is not a problem ... I bet that it's rather parsing the empty string

Comment: I have added all the tings you asked

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the 0, but in this part

```
double et1 = Double.parseDouble(ET1.getText().toString());
double et2 = Double.parseDouble(ET2.getText().toString());
double et3 = Double.parseDouble(ET3.getText().toString());
double et4 = Double.parseDouble(ET4.getText().toString());
double et5 = Double.parseDouble(ET5.getText().toString());
```

Here the error occurs when either of ET2,ET3,ET4,ET5 is empty string ("") and cannot be parsed to a double.

Therefore, you need to check it via a condition like this:

```
if(!ET1.getText().toString().equals("") && !ET2.getText().toString().equals("") &&
   !ET3.getText().toString().equals("") && !ET4.getText().toString().equals("") &&
   !ET5.getText().toString().equals("")) {
//double parsing code here
} else {
//code to run if either of the fields are empty
}
```

You were already doing it for ET1, but ET1 only, you gotta do that for all as any of those fields could be empty. I hope that helps.

Comment: I'd do this `double et1 = ET1.getText().toString()==string.Empty :0?Double.parseDouble(ET1.getText().toString());` Might also want to regex all non numeric characters out of the string first too, and store the string as a variable before converting to double, to prevent having to go to ET1 and parse the value so much.

Comment: Yeah, many improvements can be done to achieve this in a better way, but I just decided to give OP the basic idea of what he should be doing.

Comment: That's fair, but I'd never want to test all of them in a single `if` like that.

Answer (score 0):

This will never matter, anything minus zero is itself, `totaal-et1` where `et1=0` is `totaal`. Just let it do the math and don't over complicate your code trying to do something that won't change the result.

You won't be saving on processing, since basic math using the 0's is faster than the checks to see if they are 0 and rewrite the math. You won't be saving space, since your code will balloon in size.

Now that you included the rest of your code your issue makes more sense.

```
string et1s =regex.replace(ET1.getText().toString(),"[^0-9.,]",""); 
double et1 = et1s ==string.Empty :0?Double.parseDouble(et1s);
```

First line takes the input, removes everything that isn't a number from 0-9 or a decimal '.' or ',', second line takes the result of the first line and checks that there is something there then tries to convert it to a decimal. A word of warning, this will still cause an issue if the user enters multiple decimals or just a decimal and no actual number. It can still be improved on but it will solve many of the issues you have.